# For and if in dataframe column - add to another dataframe some rows before

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I try to run over my data and check if one column (rain) is bigger that 0 in case if true, I need to take 100 rows before the i index,In case the i smaller than 100 I ignored it and continue the run, and added them to another dataframe. 
My code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('weather_forecast.csv')
data_before_rain = pd.DataFrame()
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    if row['rain'] > 1:
        data_before_rain.append(data.iloc[(index-100):index])

print(data_before_rain)
```

Example of the DataFrame data:

```
                  time  ghi  dni  ...  barometric_pressure  rain  sensor_cleaning
0     01/07/2018 07:14   34    0  ...                981.8   0.1                0
1     01/07/2018 07:15   34    0  ...                981.9   0.0                0
2     01/07/2018 07:16   35    0  ...                981.9   0.0                0
3     01/07/2018 07:17   36    0  ...                981.9   0.0                0
4     01/07/2018 07:18   37    0  ...                981.9   0.1                0
5     01/07/2018 07:19   38    0  ...                982.0   0.0                0
6     01/07/2018 07:20   39    0  ...                982.0   0.0                0
7     01/07/2018 07:21   40    0  ...                982.0   0.0                0
8     01/07/2018 07:22   42    0  ...                982.0   0.0                0
9     01/07/2018 07:23   43    0  ...                982.0   0.0                0
10    01/07/2018 07:24   44    0  ...                982.0   0.0                0
11    01/07/2018 07:25   45    0  ...                982.0   0.1                0
12    01/07/2018 07:26   46    0  ...                982.1   0.0                0
```

When I try instead of `append()` method the `=` (`data_before_rain = data.iloc[index-100:index]`), it's work just for the last 100 lines.
When I try `append()` method the output is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Check what `for i in data:` is actually doing (try `for i in data: print(i)`). (Hint, dataframes have their own iteration method, `df.iterrows()`)

Comment: @Ram Rahamim if `rain > 1` then get last 100 rows and put to the new df, if there is no 100 rows before `rain > 1` the pass and continue searching?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data formatted like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

random_data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 49)
random_data = np.append(random_data, 1.1)
random_data = np.append(random_data, np.random.uniform(0, 1, 59))
random_data = np.append(random_data, 1.1)
random_data = np.append(random_data, np.random.uniform(0, 1, 139))
random_data = np.append(random_data, 1.1)
random_data = np.append(random_data, np.random.uniform(0, 1, 20))

df = pd.DataFrame({'data':np.linspace(1,150,150), 'rain':random_data})
```

Find rows where rain > 1, find proper index that is greater than 100 and finally get last 100 rows counting from found index.

```
fit_list = df.index[df['rain'] > 1].to_list()
proper_index_list = [x for x in fit_list if x > 100]
df_list = []
for index in proper_index_list:
    out = df.iloc[index-100: index]
    df_list.append(out)

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

**Output:**

```
           data      rain
9      5.985130  0.105051
..          ...       ...
244  136.152416  0.968460
248  138.368030  0.989770

df_shape = (200, 2)
```

Comment: I edited my question. rain appear sometimes as bigger than 1 and I need all the rows in one dataframe.

Comment: @RamRahamim you get 100 last rows before index with `rain > 1`. Don't understand what you mean with last comment.

Comment: I don't just need the last 100 rows. I need to add to a dataframe 100 rows when rain is bigger than 1. For example if rain bigger than 1 at line 3677 and in line 6832, the new dataframe need to include lines 3577-3676 and 6732-6731

Comment: @RamRahamim when for each occurrence of `rain >1` get last 100 rows and add them to new df? BY last comment you mean ranges: 3577-3676 and 6732-6831?

Comment: Yes :). Every time to the data_before_rain. And yes there are ranges.